# C - Turn void** into char* easily?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

One of my data structures is an array of type `void*`. It does this because it allows for any type of data to be inputted without me having to hard code types.

In this case, this data structure now contains and array of `void*` where each `void*` is actually a pointer to a character.

Is there a way I can treat this array as a `char*` (meaning an array of characters) or do I have to loop through it, add into a new array by retrieving values, etc?

```
// this is not my actual code, just demonstration
char v = 'A';

size_t size = 10;
void** myArr = malloc(sizeof(void*) * size);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
{
    char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(char));
    *ptr = v++;
    myArr[i] = ptr; // ptr here gets casted into a void*
}
char *end = malloc(sizeof(char));
*end = '\0';
myArr[size - 1] = end;

/*
* I now want to turn myArr into an array of characters,
meaning I could call printf and it would successfully print the array
with printf("%s", <something here>);
*/
char* arrayInStringForm = *(char**)myArr; // I don't think this can work.
// Any way to do it without looping or using more memory?
printf("%s\n", arrayInStringForm);


// Expected output:
// A B C D E F G H I J
```

Comment: Define "works"? What is the data? What behaviour do you expect? Are you simply asking whether you may use `char*` to inspect arbitrary data?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I fixed my question and made it clear what I'm asking. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Avoid void pointers is a great idea

Comment: @EdHeal I can't, because how else can I have a variable that accepts any data type? I need to be able to make `hashmap` of type `char` and then maybe `hashmap` of type `myStruct` and the only way I can do that is having `void*` pointing to the data elements.

Comment: Nope, still unclear. Oh well.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I have an array of pointers where each index points to a character. I want to parse that into a C-String without looping. That is my question.

Comment: How on earth are you able to interpret the data. Perhaps a union is required

Comment: A C-String saying what? You give no information about the format or encoding of the data.

Comment: A C String is just an array of type `char`. If you claim that a CString is an array of type `char` with a terminating `\0`, then yes, and that's why at the end of my array of pointers, the last pointer is pointing to a char whose' value is `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I don't understand yourt question either...

There is no need for optimization here, since `printf` will eventually call I/O functions that will span across thousands of instructions (imagine what your CPU will go through if your characters happen to trigger a window scrolling).

Whatever the origin of your mysterious characters might be, the time needed to generate a proper C-string out of them will be utterly neglectible.

So just loop over them and put them in a basic array of characters, add a `\0` terminator, call a `printf("%s"`..., and Bob will be your happy uncle.

Comment: I've updated my question accordingly. Once I get it into `char**` I'm not exactly sure how to get to to `char*` without some kind of looping though. I need to be able to pass this into a function like `printf` and have it be very very fast

Comment: Calling `*typedArray` won't work right, because that will simply get only a pointer to a single character, not a pointer to them all (because they are all not next to eachother in memory?)

Comment: If you want to display 10 characters, then allocate 11 characters (`char * s = (char *) malloc(11);`), put a terninating `\0` at the end (`s[10]='\0'`) and fill it as a simple array of characters (`for (i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) s[i] = whatever I fancy;`). The whole lot of chars will then be displayable with a `printf ("%s", s)`.

Comment: Yes you're right but i just wrote that for an example. You can see my expected output I wrote is `9` characters as `size` in this case includes the terminating `\0`.